# Portfolio to show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I like to have a portfolio that is dynamic and simple to update.

In one part there will be some little square preview, and hovering or clicking on these preview will update the LARGE section with the whole job.

I know pretty good the : `MM_swapImage()`, but like to do it in jquery or ajax.

How can I do that?

Some research result : http://code.google.com/p/jquery-swapimage/

--

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function swap(pic1, pic2)
{
var pic1 = document.getElementById("pic1");
var pic2 = document.getElementById("pic2");
var pic1src = pic1.src;
var pic2src = pic2.src;
pic2.src = pic1src;
pic1.src = pic2src;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: "simple to update" and Ajax does not go together easily..

Comment: I like a "simple to update" way to work as. The first thumbnail will be named image01-thumb.jpg, and the hr version will be name image01-hr.jpg, so this way, when there will be 25 images, the processe will still work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code (just an example, it needs changes to work for you)

```
$('#imageswitch img').hover(
                function () {
                    var oldsource = $(this).attr('src');
                    var foldername = oldsource.substr(0, oldsource.lastIndexOf('/'));
                    var filename = oldsource.replace(foldername+'/','');
                    var newsource = foldername + '/' + 'hover_' + filename;
                    $(this).attr('src', newsource);
                    $(this).data('src', oldsource);                   
                }, 
                function () {
                    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
                }
            );
```

Create a folder for the images. 
The small images are called:
image_1.jpg

the larger images are called
hover_image_1.jpg

(note the 'hover_' before the filename)

Hover over an image and it replaces it's source with the new source (the larger image), when you leave the image with the mouse the old source is restored.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution would be to store the larger filename in the `rel` tag, and use that to swap the source of a larger image on the page. You could expand this with fade-in and fade-out effects, but I'll provide only the base here:

```
<img class="thumbnail" rel="image01-hr.jpg" src="image01-thumb.jpg" />
<img class="thumbnail" rel="image02-hr.jpg" src="image02-thumb.jpg" />
<img class="preview" src="image01-hr.jpg" />

$(".thumbnail").click(function(e){
  $(".preview").attr("src", $(this).attr("rel"));
});
```